# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function litespeed_purge() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, lightspeed

I'm getting this(PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function litespeed_purge()) error when I'm trying to call the Lightspeed Cache plugin function.

Here is my code

```
$pages_to_clear_cache = array(
        'https://www.com/xxx/',
        'https://www.com/yyy/',
    );

    foreach ($pages_to_clear_cache as $page_url) {
        litespeed_purge($page_url);
        litespeed_build_cache($page_url);
    }
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Make sure the class/file containing the function is included.

Comment: Are you using it in Wordpress? Laravel? another one?

Comment: Is the supplied code called in a specific action?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for where those functions are documented? Checking the current official WordPress plugin I'm not finding it, but maybe you are using an older version or something else?

Comment: Need more info. Are you using a plugin? Custom copy/paste code? We need to know where all code resides in order to begin thinking about this. The error is clear; the function is not (yet) available

Comment: I'm using custom function here with above code and try to call the LS plugin functions but it's give me an error.